# How to store elements in javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build a card game in which two players gets random cards and the one who gets the highest sum of cards wins.

I tried pushing the generated random number into array .The trouble here is the new number should add to array but instead its going off leaving array empty. Could someone please help me.

```js
 var varCounter = 1;
    var refVar = setInterval(function() {
    
      if (varCounter <= 4) {
    
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        var player1 = [];
        player1.push(randomnumber);
    
        for (var i = 0; i < player1.length; i++) {
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write("player1 " + i + "card");
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write(player1[i]);
    
        }
        varCounter++;
      } else if (varCounter >= 5 && varCounter <= 8) {
        var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        var player2 = [];
        player2.push(randomnumber2);
        for (var i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write("player2 " + i + "card");
          document.write("<br>");
          document.write(player2[i]);
        }
        varCounter++;
      } else {
        clearInterval(refVar);
      }
    }, 100);
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
player1 1card
9
player1 2card
12
player1 3card
4
player1 4card
12
player2 1card
5
player2 2card
7
player2 3card
9
player2 4card
2
```

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
player1 0card
9
player1 0card
12
player1 0card
4
player1 0card
12
player2 0card
5
player2 0card
7
player2 0card
9
player2 0card
2
```

Comment: On every loop you do `var player1 = []` which creates a new array. The array never gets a chance to get more than one element.

Comment: @GabeRogan has nothing to do with closure.

Comment: Thank you so much Gabe Rogan .Even changing it to let i haven't changed my output.

Comment: Changing to `let` isn't going to change the output, as in every interval tick you reinitialize your `player` arrays as @JJJ also said. Therefore, the `i` iterator in your loop is always `0`. Try moving those two out of the `setInterval()`. Or if you only want to show the `1 2 3 4card`, use `document.write("player " + varCounter%4 + "card");`

Comment: You should not use document.wrtie.

Comment: Thnakyou so much @JJJ .I appreciate that.

Comment: Thnakyou so much @ionizer .great to know the use of  "%". Just started learning JS.

Comment: Thank you !! @epascarello .Do you have any suggestions apart from document.write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you only wanted the desired output. I changed `varCounter`-related code so it works with the `varCounter` modulo `%` nicely and made it into runnable snippet.

```js
var varCounter = 0;
var refVar = setInterval(function() {

  if (varCounter < 4) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var player1 = [];
    player1.push(randomnumber);

    for (var i = 0; i < player1.length; i++) {
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player1 " + (varCounter%4+1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player1[i]);

    }
    varCounter++;
  } else if (varCounter >= 4 && varCounter < 8) {
    var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    var player2 = [];
    player2.push(randomnumber2);
    for (var i = 0; i < player2.length; i++) {
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player2 " + (varCounter%4+1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player2[i]);
    }
    varCounter++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(refVar);
  }
}, 100);
```

Or if you really want the result which you fill the array with card values, (EDITED: Removed the `for` loops, add in the `for` loops again to check the array content)

```js
var varCounter = 0;

var player1 = [];
var player2 = [];

var refVar = setInterval(function() {

  if (varCounter < 4) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    player1.push(randomnumber);

    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("player1 " + (varCounter%4+1) + "card");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(player1[varCounter%4] + " "); //Removed for loop

    varCounter++;
  } else if (varCounter >= 4 && varCounter < 8) {
    var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    player2.push(randomnumber2);

    document.write("<br>");
    document.write("player2 " + (varCounter%4+1) + "card");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(player2[varCounter%4] + " "); //Removed for loop

    varCounter++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(refVar);
  }
}, 100);
```

EDIT:
**OP's Final Answer:**

```js
var varCounter = 0;
var player1 = [];
var player2 = [];
var refVar = setInterval(function() {
  if (varCounter <= 3) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    player1.push(randomnumber);
    var i = varCounter % 4;
    for (i; i < player1.length; i++) {

      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player1 " + (i + 1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player1[i]);

    }
    varCounter++;
  } else if (varCounter >= 4 && varCounter <= 7) {
    var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    player2.push(randomnumber2);
    var i = varCounter % 4;
    for (i; i < player2.length; i++) {

      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player2 " + (i + 1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player2[i]);

    }
    varCounter++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(refVar);
  }
}, 100)
```

Comment: I think the array is not storing in first code snippet. Excuse me if 'm wrong

Comment: The first one is just to fix the `"player " + i +"card"` output so it goes `1card 2card 3card 4card`. So yes, it always has only a single element and not storing more.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments on your question pointed out, your arrays `player1` and `player2` get overwritten each time you iterate through your counter as it's contained within the iteration, if you like to write something with every iteration, I suggest taking out your `for` loop like this:

```
if (varCounter <= 4) {
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  var player1 = [];
  player1.push(randomnumber);

  document.write("<br>");
  document.write("player1 " + varCounter + "card"); // varCounter becomes your 1 2 3 4card
  document.write("<br>");
  document.write(player1);

  varCounter++;
}
```

Or exploring a `while` loop like this: https://codepen.io/corviday/pen/pdMyEw?editors=1010

Hope this helps!

Comment: That needs to be `varCounter%4 + 1`. But most importantly, does this work?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally came up with.

```js
var varCounter = 0;
var player1 = [];
var player2 = [];
var refVar = setInterval(function() {
  if (varCounter <= 3) {
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    player1.push(randomnumber);
    var i = varCounter % 4;
    for (i; i < player1.length; i++) {

      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player1 " + (i + 1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player1[i]);

    }
    varCounter++;
  } else if (varCounter >= 4 && varCounter <= 7) {
    var randomnumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (13 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

    player2.push(randomnumber2);
    var i = varCounter % 4;
    for (i; i < player2.length; i++) {

      document.write("<br>");
      document.write("player2 " + (i + 1) + "card");
      document.write("<br>");
      document.write(player2[i]);

    }
    varCounter++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(refVar);
  }
}, 100)
```

Comment: @ionizer Yes,when I inspect that its working.I can see the length increasing. Is there an another way to check the array?

Comment: You're welcome. One last thing though, you don't seem to need the `for` loop anymore as I shown in my edited answer. Just a little optimization :)